# Checking absolute irreducibility

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

How can one check if a polynomial $f$  is absolutely irreducible ?  (meaning that it is irreducible over the closure of the underlying field. Example: $y^{2} - x^{3}$ is absolutely irreducible ( the underlying field being rational numbers) while $y^{2}+x^{2}$ is not)